# Как я могу передать пароль в bash команду

Tags: linux, bash

В скрипте нужно выполнить команду:

```
adcli join --domain=domain.local --login-user=user
```

эта команда запрашивает пароль, как его передать средствами баша?

пробовал `echo "password" | adcli join --domain=domain.local --login-user=user` не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из
[документации](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/realmd/adcli/adcli.html):

> ```
> --stdin-password   Read a password from stdin input instead of prompting for a password.
> ```

Comment: А не подскажите еще, что лишнего может передаваться при такой конструкции:
echo 'Password'|adcli join --domain=domainr.local --login-user=user --stdin-password
получаю ошибку аутентификации, хотя пароль 100% корректный
ошибка:
adcli: couldn't connect to domain.local domain: Couldn't authenticate as: user@domain.local: Preauthentication failed

Comment: Предположу, что перенос строки.  `echo -n`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.